# Thymeleaf 3 native fragments for script tags at the end of page

Tags: thymeleaf

Thymeleaf 3 has build-in fragments support (no need for `nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect` dependency).

I am not experienced with Thymeleaf and would like to see code that allows to define some `script` tags for inclusion inside `head` tag and some tags for inclusion before `</body>` end tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HTML file like this ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th=“http://www.thymeleaf.org”>
<head th:fragment=“head”>
    <script>
    …
    </script>
<head>

<body>
    <div th:fragment="foot">
      …
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

... defines two fragments: `head` and `foot` which can then be referenced in other Thymeleaf templates like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th=“http://www.thymeleaf.org”>
<head>
    <!—/*/  <th:block th:include=“fragments/main :: head"><.th:block>  /*/—>

    … other stuff specific to this template
</head>
<body>
    … other stuff specific to this template

    <!—/*/  <th:block th:include=“fragments/main :: foot"><.th:block>  /*/—>
</body>
</html>
```

The include instruction (`<th:block th:include=“fragments/main :: head"`) describes the location of the file which contains the fragment (`fragments/main`) and the name of a specific fragment within that file (`head`) so my example assumes that the HTML file containing the fragments is named `main` and that it is located in a folder named `fragments` relative to the location of the template file(s) which use these fragments. For example:

```
+- templates
    |
    +- fragments
      |
      + main.html
    +- index.html
    +- … etc
```